# Java Logging Framework and Log Analyzer

Tags: java, logging

I'm developing over Primefaces with EJB3. I need a logging framework to monitor and track application's users and extract statistics. Does anyone know, what options I have for both logging and log analyzing?

Thanks in adavnce

Comment: Do you need to know how to _log_ the information in the first place, or how to generate reports from your logs?

Comment: Actually the second is that I need. I already used logging frameworks and am familiar with logging concepts. I want to know how can I generate reports from my logs

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Simple Logging Facade for Java (SLF4J)

Answer (score 0):

Solution depends on your requirements. You can log it to text file with any log library like log4j and analyze using linux utils like grep/awk/etc, or write it to database and analyze with SQL, or write to NoSQL storage and alalyze it using your code.

Comment: My application is enterprise so needs enterprise logging. It has about one million users and about one thousand online users at any time. I need to audit all users' activities and calculate some statistics about the web pages' visits. I already used Log4j in my project and familiar with logging concepts. What framework fits my requirement? can you suggest anything?

Comment: What problems with log4j do you have now? What do you want to have, that log4j doesn't provide?

Comment: I want to know how can I generate reports from my logs. Should I change my logging framework to be able to generate reports? What framework can I use for reports?

Comment: If you are using log4j than you can use unix command line tools to build reports. Check this page, for example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unix_utilities Especially about grep/sed/awk.

Answer (score 0):

I have always used log4j for logging as it is not that hard to set up and has most of the features one would need. You can find it [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/). I have never used a log analyzer before but it seems apache has one to analyze log4j output: [chainsaw](http://logging.apache.org/chainsaw/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Java provides an efficient logging framework. With plenty of logging levels : 
FINE, FINER, FINEST, WARNING, SEVERE.

Moreover, You have another extensive logging framework log4j with Levels DEBUG, SEVERE etc.

Chose whatever you want. Log4j is easier if you want to push different logs in different files.

You can later analyze with grep/awk utils in linux as mentioned by dbf.

Answer (score 0):

You clarified that you were not looking for how to log, but how to process the logs.

First of all there is viewers, Apache Chainsaw for log4j, and [Lilith](http://lilith.huxhorn.de/) for logback+log4j+JDK14 logging.  This is useful for seeing just the items you need.

For dedicated report generators I do not believe there is any based on raw logs.  You may, however, use the Unix utilities `grep`, `awk`/`perl` to extract the information you need and manually generate input files to visualization tools or report generators.  Problem here is that the things you typically want to know from logs are hard to predict.  If you have an actual need then find out how you can generate the information you need using logs (markers in slf4j are nice) and then just post massage those logs into the format you need for further processing.